# Pandas dataframe from numpy with last dimension as object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Convert 3d numpy array to pandas dataframe with numpy.array as elements.
Are there any other solutions? What about speed?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
    
ones = np.ones((2,3,5))
temp = [[np.array(column_elem, dtype=np.object) for column_elem in row] for row in ones]
df = pd.DataFrame(temp)
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_records(ones)` ?

Comment: Haha, yes, that what i was looking for! Thank you

Comment: why don't you read the docs and post an answer for the benefit of others? i'll upvote it if its well written